Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) VBA code shutting down excel
I am trying to write VBA code to automatically add the value of one cell into another cell. For example, if a '1' is entered into E9 then a '1' should then be entered into E11. Here are two different ways I wrote the code and every time excel closes.
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Worksheets("BWI Hardware").Range("E9") > 0 Then
    Worksheets("BWI Hardware").Range("E11") = Worksheets("BWI Hardware").Range("E9")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
If Sheet18.Range("E9").Value > 0 Then
Range("E9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End If

 With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
End Sub


You're changing the worksheet within the event handler, causing it to fire in an infinite loop. See the linked thread for how to safely and temporarily disable events.
